# How to dump NSHomeDirectory file listing to NSLog

Tags: iphone, nslog

Is there a quick way to spit out a directory listing for a specific folder in NSHomeDirectory?  I'm playing with an example in [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) that downloads an image via:

```
[request setDownloadDestinationPath:[[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"totallyhotmilf.jpg"]];
```

I'd like to list the files in the Documents folder to see whats actually getting downloaded for debugging purposes.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found an answer to my question thanks to [this page](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/data-file-management/save-uiimage-object-as-a-png-or-jpeg-file.html).  This will give you a nice file listing:

```
// Create file manager
NSError *error;
NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

// Point to Document directory
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];

// Write out the contents of home directory to console
NSLog(@"Documents directory: %@", [fileMgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error]);
```